# Доступ к переменной другого метода в классе

Tags: python, классы

Возможно ли получить доступ переменной, находящейся в другом методе одного класса?

```
class Examlple():

    def getString(self):
        self.string = 'spam'
        return self.string

    def printOut(self):
        self.another_string = self.string
        print self.another_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui = Examlple()
    gui.printOut()
```

Этот код выдает ошибку:

```
`AttributeError: Examlple instance has no attribute 'string'`
```

Comment: если вы создаете string только в getString, то он и не будет существовать до вызова getString

Comment: @Fike Так работает, но насколько это правильно?

    `def printOut(self):
        self.getString()
        self.another_string = self.string
        print self.another_string`

Comment: А зачем вам все эти манипуляции?

Почему нельзя сделать сразу:

    def printOut(self):
        print self.getString()
        # или как вариант:
        # another_string = self.getString()
        # print another_string

И зачем в printOut использовать self.another_string (почему именно self?), если он используется только для вывода? Объявите переменную без self.

И еще - почему `getString()` (`получить строку`) кроме всего прочего еще и устанавливает self.string?

Лучше определить self.string вне метода, инициализировать в конструкторе, а getString и printOut используют уже готовое значение

Comment: @to_night, это зависит исключительно от того, что вы хотите в своей программе реализовать. Если getString не распухнет, то в нем особого смысла вообще нет.

Comment: @ВОРОН Спасибо. Это тестовый код, чтобы разъяснить проблему в реальном коде.